# How Do I add Pins (Annotations) with Xcode 6 (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, swift, xcode6

I'm new to the swift language, and haven't done an application with mapkit yet. But I have the map and regions set, but I'm hung up on how to allow users to add pins. 
Let me clarify, I have no idea of even where to start, All I have at the moment (for the pins) is my variable, but I'm not even sure if that's correct. Any help would be much appreciated!!
What I have...

var MyPins: MKPinAnnotatoinView!

......

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Mapview code

.....
.....
}

Answer (score 38):

Your pin variable is correct. Now you just need to add this annotation to `MKMapView`.

You can also create a custom class for `MKAnnotation` to add custom annotation to map view.

*A beta demo for **[MapExampleiOS8](http://jmp.sh/g6bgmcC)** => Which supports **Swift 2.1***

Follow steps below:

**1. Add `MapKit.framework` to project.**

[image]

**2. Create Storyboard variable `IBOutlet` of map view control or create it in view controller. Set delegate for this variable to override it's delegate methods:**

Add delegate signature to view controller interface:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set map view delegate with controller
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**3. Override its delegate methods:**

Here we need to override `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)` method to show annotation pins on map.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    if (annotation.isKind(of: CustomAnnotation.self)) {
        let customAnnotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "CustomAnnotation") as MKAnnotationView!

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = customAnnotation?.annotationView()
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation;
        }

        self.addBounceAnimationToView(annotationView)
        return annotationView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**4. Add `MKPointAnnotation` to map view.**

You can add pin to location in map view. For simplicity add code to `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set map view delegate with controller
    self.mapView.delegate = self

    let newYorkLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730872, -74.003066)
    // Drop a pin
    let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    dropPin.coordinate = newYorkLocation
    dropPin.title = "New York City"
    mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call a method for when and where the user needs to add the pin. If you want it to add a pin where the user taps and holds on the map, you will need to call a gestureRecognizer, but if you want to do it via a button you will obviously just call that in an action. Either way the documentation for adding pins is throughly discussed [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW33)